# Python Fraction Type Not Simplifying Correctly

Tags: python, debugging, types, fractions

The Python Fraction type, as I understand it, outputs the simplified version of whatever you put inside it (i.e. print(Fraction(4/8)) prints out 1/2). However, for certain inputs I'm getting really weird results:

Fraction(984/1920) should output 41/80, but instead gives 
2308094809027379/4503599627370496.

Fraction(1000/992) should output 125/124, but instead gives 4539918979204129/4503599627370496.

Fraction(408/896) should output 51/112, but instead gives 8202985035567689/18014398509481984.

When I input the correctly simplified fraction into the Fraction type, I get the same buggy representation - same massive values, even. There are many more examples where these came from. Any ideas as to why this is the case, and what I can do to remedy it?

Answer (score 3):

Use a comma to separate the numerator and denominator:

```
>>> Fraction(984/1920)
Fraction(2308094809027379, 4503599627370496)
>>> Fraction(984, 1920)
Fraction(41, 80)
```

Using `/` means that the binary-floating point division takes place first, *before* the inputs are passed to *Fraction*.  So, the displayed fraction is for the binary floating point number after it has been rounded to a fraction with 53-bits of precision in the numerator and a power-of-two for the denominator:

```
>>> 984 / 1920
0.5125
>>> (0.5125).as_integer_ratio()
(2308094809027379, 4503599627370496)
```

By separating the arguments to *Fraction*, you are passing in exact integers for the numerator and denominator, which can then be reduced to lowest terms using the greatest-common-denominator algorithm.